# How to change fields in ldap in python?

Tags: python, ldap

How to change a field (in my case fax) in ldap in python? Here are the fields -

```
    base = 'name'
    score = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
    filter = "(&(mail=))"
    attrs = ['mail', 'fax', ...]
    result_set = []

    ldap_result_id = []                       
    lconn.search_ext(base, score,     
    filter, attributes)

    lconn = ldap.initialize('name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `modify()` function. It takes an entry DN and a list of value changes (add value(s); replace all values; delete value or delete attribute; increment).

```
changes = [
    (ldap.MOD_REPLACE, "fax",         "+1234".encode()),
    (ldap.MOD_ADD,     "newAttr",     [b"Value A", b"Value B"]),
    (ldap.MOD_DELETE,  "uselessAttr", []),
]

lconn.modify(dn, changes)
```

Operations are applied in the order they're specified. Each operation may specify either a single value or a list of values, that is, `bytes | list[bytes]`. (To remove a whole attribute, specify an empty list for the REPLACE or DELETE operation.)

The API provided by the `ldap` module is not very python-friendly; it requires you to provide every value as a bytestring, so you must manually encode() regular strings (and str()ingify integers). Meanwhile, the attribute *name* is still a regular string.

Note that values used as part of the DN itself cannot be changed through modify() – e.g. if you have an entry with a DN of `CN=Foo,OU=Bar,[...]`, then the `CN: Foo` attribute is a *naming* attribute and changing this value would entail renaming the entry, which uses the `modrdn()` function. (But at the same time, if it's a multi-valued attribute, then other values which are *not* used in the RDN can still be changed via modify().)